# Possible add 3 outcome of If Condition in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have If condition with one expression. Activity seems to support only True and False.

I would like to have 3 different outcome. Possible values are "A", "B" or "C"

It is possible with any tool or should I have If condition inside if condition?

Comment: Do you want to check among three set of values? if A or B or C?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use Switch Activity: It could work on different possible outcomes

[Switch Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-switch-activity)

Sample:

I have a pipeline that assigns a value to a variable based on parameter passed during runtime

[image: Pipeline]

the expression in my set variable activity is:

```
@string(mul(int(pipeline().parameters.flagvalue),10))
```

I am multiplying the parameter value by 10 and assigning to a vaiable called outflag.

Then in the switch activity i am checking the value of outflag as below

[image: Switch Expression]

In each switch case, you can have as many activities as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have IF activity within another IF activity directly.
One way is create a pipeline with 1 if activity call it in another pipeline within IF activity via execute pipeline activity.
Or
You can use Switch activity for multiple scenarios.